# TTS android 4.1 jellybean

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have English data installed for TTS and it works, but when calling

```
tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Always returns -2 ( CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA ) on android 4.1 . The only way i have found to make it pass the test, using a nexus 7 tablet , is to install all the other TTS data files, French , Italian etc , then it reports the correct result.
I am now showing a message to the user to install the files and the option to install English is not shown because its already installed, in other words this message is now shown everytime  the app is used, which is obviously annoying.

Android [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36430)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for Locale.US or Locale.UK

Comment: This gives the same result (-2)

Comment: It sounds like a android 4.1 issue. Have you tried it on an older version?

Comment: yes , this is a 4.1 issue that's why i mention it specifically in the title

Answer (score 0):

`Locale.US` stands for US English ("en_US"). Try to pass just "en":

```
    tts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("en"));
```